# Does GROMACS have the capability to do Monte Carlo simulation of proteins?

Tags: gromacs, monte-carlo

My supervisor says that GROMACS can do both (all-atom) MD and MC simulations of proteins.

I never found anything while searching the Internet about MC-only simulations. As far as I found, GROMACS can do MD+MC hybrid smulation, not pure MC.

Does GROMACS have the capability to do Monte Carlo simulations of proteins?